# How to set background color for svg text tspan without foreign object?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

This is My code, How to set the attr("background-color","red")

```
var datacollection = stackmap.append("text")
.attr("x", 40)
.attr("y", 50)
.attr("fill", "#8b8b8b")
.attr("font", "14px segoe ui")
.append("tspan")
.text("*content  :  Oh My God " + window.year);
```

Answer (score 1):

svg `text` elements do not have the concept of 'background', you can only style the actual text itself.  If you'd like have a background you will need to add that separately with, for instance, an svg `rect` element:

```
stackmap.append("rect")
    .attr({
      "class": "background",
      x: 40,
      y: 50,
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    })
    .style("fill", "red");
stackmap.append("text")
    ..etc
```

Comment: How would you then size the rectangle according to the size of the text?

Comment: @hofnarwillie You can use domElemen.getClientRects() to get the rectangles representing the boxes surrounding the text.